# How to Link lapack and BLAS library to C++ code

Tags: c++, gcc, lapack, blas, armadillo

The above are linear algebra libraries. i am using armadillo which is like a c++ wrapper/framework for linking to more basic linear algebra libraries in fortran.

I can compile the example.cpp easily by having a #include "armadillo" using gcc -c option with the -I flag.
This generates example.o which is now supposed to be linked to liblapack_LINUX.a and libBLAS_linux.a Statically

Locations of the two:

```
liblapack_LINUX.a :-/home/nimish/HTMLProjects/WP2/lib/lapack/
libBLAS_linux.a :-/home/nimish/HTMLProjects/WP2/lib/blas
```

I issue the following command:

```
gcc -o example.o -L../lib/blas -lblas_LINUX -L../lib/lapack -llapack_LINUX
```

OR with absolute paths

```
nimish@ubuntu:~$ gcc -o example.o -L/home/nimish/HTMLProjects/WP2/lib/blas -lblas_LINUX    -L/home/nimish/HTMLProjects/WP2/lib/lapack -llapack_LINUX
```

to get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas_LINUX
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However the libraries do exist --

```
nimish@ubuntu:~$ find /home/nimish/HTMLProjects/WP2 -name liblapack_LINUX.a
/home/nimish/HTMLProjects/WP2/lib/lapack/liblapack_LINUX.a

nimish@ubuntu:~$ find /home/nimish/HTMLProjects/WP2 -name libblas_LINUX.a
/home/nimish/HTMLProjects/WP2/lib/BLAS/libblas_LINUX.a
```

What am i doing wrong? I am somewhat new to this linking libraries business as well as gcc.

Comment: You have a wrong command at first: do `gcc example.o -o example ...`. And the second: try to put flags before object files: `gcc -L... -l... example.o -o example`.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to ensure you have BLAS installed using(+lapack)

sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev

then you can link using -lblas after your program files. or you can use a make file.

from my side I prefer to use OpenBlas instead, you can use the following in a makefile.

1. [www.openblas.net](http://www.openblas.net), get the tar.gz
   copy it in your directory
2. extract it : tar -zxvf OpenBLAS-0.2.20.tar.gz
3. compile it : cd OpenBLAS-0.2.20
   make

When it is done you should have the file libopenblas.a, the openblas library

- BLASLIB =  OpenBLAS/libopenblas.a -lpthread