# Missing librefblas.a

Tags: fortran, linker-errors, gfortran, blas

Trying to compile some Fortran code using gfortran 9.x.x on my CentOS 7.xx machine. Have a particular version of the code that requires linking to LAPACK and BLAS (specifcially, liblapack.a, and librefblas.a). Have LAPACK (and all the -devel libs), and BLAS (same about -devel libs) installed (both available in the CentOS base repo).

While I (and therefore the linker) can find liblapack.a (its in /usr/lib64), no trace of librefblas.a (which causes the linker to complain bitterly, and the compilation to crash and burn).

In fact, I tried installing both BLAS and OpenBLAS on the same machine, but that didn't help -- librefblas.a still nowhere to be found.

Comment: you can fix that, just go to my answer there,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66440738/10095440

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to try is to use the regular `libblas`. Either change your Makefile to to use `libblas` instead of `librefblas` or make a symlink.  Then check if you have any unresolved reference. Or do the same for OpenBLAS and point your makefile to `libopenblas`. Note that OpenBLAS also includes LAPACK.

Background: BLAS and LAPACK are publicly available interfaces. There is a reference implementation available, but also many alternative optimized or machine-specific ones. It should not matter which one you use so it seems unnecessary to specifically require the reference one. Normally, your Linux distribution `libblas` is the reference one anyway. It is probably just a quirk of your Makefile.

Comment: Bingo -- thanks.  I think I knew that about a lifetime ago, but your thorough and helpful note both reminded me, and clarified things. libblas did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> no trace of librefblas.a

The CentOS 7 lapack-3.4.2-8.el7 package build doesn't create or install the file librefblas.a .
I.e. no available package providing /usr/lib64/librefblas.a .
The package blas-static provides one file only : /usr/lib64/libblas.a

Build librefblas.a :

```
tar xvf lapack-3.4.2-clean.tgz
https://src.fedoraproject.org/repo/p....4.2-clean.tgz
cd lapack-3.4.2/
cp make.inc.example make.inc
make blaslib
```

... And librefblas.a will be created.

Comment: Who not just make a symlink?

Comment: librefblas.a is not equal to libblas.a : When created from the same source, the file sizes differ.

Comment: That may just be a red herring.  They should contain the same subroutines. They may compile them with some slightly different compiler options.

Comment: So, I downloaded LAPACK, and built blaslib, and then tossed the librefblas.a into /usr/lib64. It is definitely not the same size as libblas.a. Although not a rigorous test, I test-compiled various bits of numerically intensive code against either, and using simply execution time as a proxy for 'differences', found absolutely none. Meaning...not much. At least, for *my* code, using either libblas or librefblas amounts to much the same thing. At some point, I'll diff the two libs, but perhaps someone can cut to the chase and tell me what the difference is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

do this in the package folder:

```
sudo ln -s $HOME/lapack-3.9.0/librefblas.a /usr/local/lib/librefblas.a
```

solved